# Is it possible to retrieve the view_email_url for a previously sent email?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to retrieve the view_email_url for some previously sent emails.

Is view_email_url stored in a query-able data view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can get the details of View_email_url and it should be available in Click data view table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not recording the links (via a send log), it might be helpful to reach out to support. The view_email_url are is a combination of the account's domain and encrypted data that includes the job ID, batch ID, and other secret sauces. Support may be able to help you re-create that encrypted values in a way to allow you to preview the